# C: parallel processes and pick the last but one

Tags: c, unix, for-loop, process, pid

I have to write a program in C that uses processes, not threads (I'm writing in UNIX):

the father generate 7 children.
every child generate a random integer and begin an empty for statement from 0 to that random int.
at the end, the father calls wait and print the pid of the last but one process that has terminated.

this is what I'm trying:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main(){
    int n = 7;
    int i,r, random;
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t pid_padre;
    int *shared_memory;
    int segment_id;
    int size = 1024;
    int ciclo;


    pid_padre = getpid();

    printf("Inizio programma:\n");
    printf("Processo Padre: [%d]\n", pid_padre);


    segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,  size, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    shared_memory = shmat(segment_id, NULL, 0);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        shared_memory[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    pid =fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        random = rand();
        for(ciclo=0; ciclo<random; ciclo++);
            for (r=0; r<n; r++) {
                if (shared_memory[r] == 0) {
                    //printf("figlio %d\n",getpid() );
                    //shared_memory[r] = (int)getpid();
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (getpid() == pid_padre) {
        wait(NULL);
        //sleep(3);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            printf("array, figlio %d, pid \n",i , shared_memory[i]);
        }

        shmdt(shared_memory);
        shmctl(segment_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

edit: what's wrong in my code: at the end, it does print nothing instead of pids, it prints

"array, figlio 1, pid "

instead of "array, figlio 1, pid 3898" for example

Comment: you have to state what's wrong with your code

Comment: You create 7 child processes, but only wait() for one of them. And there's no need for that horrible shmem stuff. wait() will tell you the PID of each child as it exits.

Comment: wait() will tell you the PID of each child? how is it possible, I have to call 7 times the function wait() ?

Comment: Your children should `exit(0);` or `return 0;` rather than `break;`.  The use of shared memory is not obvious.

Comment: Well, at least 6, you could skip the last one since you're not interested in it. But you have to wait for 6 of them to finish before you know which one is "next to last"

Comment: The [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) system call returns the PID of the process which was waited for; the optional `int *` argument receives the exit status of the dead child.

Comment: Since your print statement is: `printf("array, figlio %d, pid \n", i, shared_memory[i]);`, you shouldn't expect to see a PID value.  You'd need a `%d` after `pid` to use the arguments to `printf()`.  Please add compiler warnings (`-Wall` at least for `gcc`) to your compilation, and sort out any problems it reports.  You still have a race condition in your code; there's a TOCTOU (time-of-check, time-of-use) problem in writing to `shared_memory[i]` if you have a multi-core CPU.

Comment: thank you everyone, I found the solution: 

I have to call 7 times wait, and save the return value in an array, than print the last but one position of that array!

thank you very much @WumpusQ.Wumbley

Comment: and, yes @JonathanLeffler , you ar right, I was missing the last %d

Comment: I just noticed the busy loop doesn't actually count up to the target either, because the condition is `ciclorandom` instead of `ciclo < ciclorandom`. It wouldn't hurt to make `ciclo` a `volatile` to make sure it doesn't get optimized out. Or usleep a random amount instead